# Passing c# DataTable as a parameter to stored procedure in MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datatable, database-cursor

I want to pass a **DataDable** to a **stored procedure as parameter** cointaning the columns below:

```
Supp_Id          int
Del_Methode_Id   int
Ord_Ammount      int
Promo_Id         int
Discount_Ammount Money
```

Now I want to use this datatable in stored procedure and want to declare a cursor on it. And use that cursor to insert values into the database table sequentially.

Please tell me how to **declare datatable parameter** in stored procedure and then using **cursor** on that **parameter** ?

Comment: There are plenty of code samples out there (found under Google's search engine). Go, and learn to find answers to simple questions yourself.

Comment: see this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39161/C-and-Table-Value-Parameters

Comment: Looks the same as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18072758/15498)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First you need to create a type:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.whatever AS TABLE
(
  Supp_Id          int, 
  Del_Methode_Id   int,
  Ord_Amount       int,
  Promo_Id         int,
  Discount_Amount  Money
);
```

Now your stored procedure can declare this as a read only input parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.do_whatever
  @datatable dbo.whatever READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT dbo.destination_table(column_list)
    SELECT column_list FROM @datatable;
END
GO
```

Why you want to use a cursor here, or think you need one, I'm not sure. You can add an `ORDER BY` clause to the `INSERT...SELECT` if you think that will be useful (and there is something meaningful to order by), but otherwise if you really really want a cursor here you should be able to declare one against `@datatable` just as you would for any other table.