# How to pass this datatable having dynamic columns to stored procedure;

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, datatable

I have a `DataTable` with dynamic columns I want to pass this `DataTable` to stored procedure.
Please explain how I can achieve this?

Comment: Have you considered passing the data table as XML?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080022/passing-c-sharp-datatable-as-a-parameter-to-stored-procedure-in-ms-sql-server-20

Answer (score 0):

declare @tbl table(...)

insert into @tbl

select * from [your datatable]

create proc sp_xyz (@tbl table)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please use formatting to make your answers/posts more readable. Also in case you can, provide some explanation.