# Pass datatable as paramater in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to pass datatable as parameter into stored procedure ?
So, something like

```
exec MyStoredProcedure @MyDataTable
```

I am using SQL SERVER 2008.

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/passing-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008/

Comment: Is it a table variable or a table name? both possible.

Comment: you can do it with table variable. Here is an example http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/214492/Passing-a-datatable-to-a-stored-procedure-in-Sql-S

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080022/passing-c-sharp-datatable-as-a-parameter-to-stored-procedure-in-ms-sql-server-20

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing datatable to a stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320594/passing-datatable-to-a-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create User-defined Table Type first.

```
-- Create the data type
CREATE TYPE udtt_Table AS TABLE 
(
    Column1     int, 
    Column2     varchar(10), 
    Column3     datetime
)
GO
```

You can use user-defined table type in your stored procedure like the following,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_User
(
    @UserTable  udtt_Table READONLY
)
...
....
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own type: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007.aspx

But it's quite a work... What exactly do you want to reach?

EDIT: Another suggestion
Use an XML-Parameter (see comments below)

Comment: I need to pass a table with data in it to stored procedure. I will work on that data inside stored procedure.

Comment: Best (at least for me) is to pass the data as XML. You can create the content easily with a SELECT [..] FOR XML [...]. Your SP or UDF can declare a parameter of type XML. That's it... The only challenge is to query an XML's fields when you are not used to it :-) (Please vote up if helpfull, thx)

Comment: The function from C# program will insert data to datatable, so the parameter must be datatable. I am editing database, my friends are working on applicaiton part and this is theirs demand.

Comment: In my work it's common practice to pass data as XML (as string) into SQL-SPs and/or SQL-UDFs. If you do so from C# (assuming you speak about System.Data.DataTable) you could have a look to the WriteXml-Method. HTH